# Blender rigging while handling cloth collision

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, cloth-simulation

I have a character whose legs are draped in some cloth. I rigged the character and parented the rig to the character mesh and the cloth mesh. So when I move the rig parts, the corresponding body parts move and so does the cloth. When I move the leg of the character, the leg and the cloth draped on it , both move. However, the leg penetrates through the cloth after some point. Is there a way to fix this? I want the leg to push the cloth, and never penetrate through it.

Comment: I would try increasing the collision quality and maybe the distances.